# What is the latin word for "smoked" or "cured"?

Tags: word-request, adjective

I need to get the proper latin drug name for "smoked jujube fruit", which might be "fructus jujube fumatus", but I suspect there might be more than one word for smoked / cured products in Latin, which were common before the era of refrigerators. What adjective is usually used with smoked food items?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I searched Lewis and Short dictionary entries for "smoked" and found the following two additional candidates:

- [fūmōsus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dfumosus): apparently used by Horace to describe "smoke-dried" meat ("fumosae [...] pernae", Hor. S. 2.2.117)
- [īnfūmātus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dinfumo): Pliny's *Natural History* apparently used "asini cerebrum [...] infumatum" to mean "smoked ass's brain" (28.225.1)

Answer (score 3):

A generic Latin word for drying and thereby preserving food is *durare*, and so you have *cibaria aliqua re durata*, e.g. *sole, muria* or *fumo*. (Expressions like *durati muria pisces* (i.e., pickled fish) indicate to me that the idea of "drying" need not be taken too literally, although smoked jujube fruit are certainly dried anyway.)

So an option would be to say **zizipha fumo durata** (plural).

Note:

- The addition of *fructus* seems neither necessary nor correct to me. *Ziziphum* is already the fruit, *ziziphus, -i,* f. would be the tree. (*Ziziphum = baca ziziphi.*)
- *Ziziphum* is classical (see Plinius, [Nat. Hist. 15, 47](https://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/L/Roman/Texts/Pliny_the_Elder/15*.html)); *jujuba, -ae,* f. is apparently a medieval word, but for the tree.